# What is the difference between "." "./" and "source"?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

What is the difference between

```
. script.sh
```

```
./script.sh
```

and

```
source script.sh
```

?

Answer (score 15):

```
./script
```

The above executes the script.  When the script is done, any changes that it made to the environment are discarded.

```
. script
```

The above sources the script.  It is as if the commands had been typed in directly.  Any environment changes are kept.

```
source script
```

This also sources the script.  The `source` command is not required by POSIX and therefore is less portable than the shorter `.`.