# why shell doesn't show anything after the command echo $VERSION

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Can somebody tell me why my command language interpreter shell shows me an empty string as the result after the command

> $ echo $VERSION

And only after executing this command

> $ . /etc/os-release

it begins to show me the result of that command

> $ echo $VERSION
>
> 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

can you, please, explain me what happens after that command? Why had not shell shown it before? Why does shell show it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running ". /etc/os-release" will run all lines in file "/etc/os-release" in your current shell; It seems that the file you are sourcing has a line like below that will set environment variable "VERSION" in your session:

```
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

If you are using bash then "source" will give you the same result: "source /etc/os-release"

You can check these in detail: https://ss64.com/bash/source.html or https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: It's a _shell_ variable that it sets; `os-release` is technically _not_ a shell script (see `man os-release`); you have missed explaining the important point that there _is no_ standard `VERSION` shell variable; and _Unix and Linux_ has https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58514/5132, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17815/5132, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/5132, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312573/5132, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459087/5132, and …

Comment: @JdeBP wow, thank you. all a matter of dot.